# How to dump and download mysql from Google Clould's VM

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, magento, google-cloud-platform

How to dump and download MySQL from Google Clould's VM?

I have a Google VM instances Cent OS. Magneto was install there with MySQL and Apache.

I want to download the database which is in Local-host.

I have tried couple of commands and it's showing "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump db | ssh test.host mysql db' at line 1"

Below are the commands did not worked.

```
mysql> mysqldump -u magento -p magento | gzip > magento.db.sql;

mysql> mysqldump -u magento -p magento > db_dump.sql;

mysql> mysqldump db | ssh test.host mysql db;

mysql> mysqldump /var/dbbackup/backup.sql;
```

Please check screenshot below. mydatabase name : magento db user name : maganto.

[image]

Comment: you can also use workbench, which gives you flexible options for importing and exporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit from MySQL Prompt and do like below from direct Linux terminal

```
$ mysqldump -uusername -p dbname > /var/dbbackup/db_backup.sql;
```